# What's wrong with realloc?

Tags: c

Started to learn malloc.h in C. The idea was to create dynamic array. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main() {
    int *array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int i, j, val;
    for (i = 0;; i++) {
        array = (int*)realloc(array, sizeof(int) + sizeof(*array));
        printf("Enter array[%d]=", i);
        scanf("%d", (array + i));
        if (*(array + i) == 0) break;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        printf("[%d] = %d\n", j, *(array + j));
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
Enter array[0]=1
Enter array[1]=2
Enter array[2]=3
Enter array[3]=4
Enter array[4]=5
Enter array[5]=6
Enter array[6]=7
Enter array[7]=8
Enter array[8]=9
Enter array[9]=10
Enter array[10]=0
[0] = 1
[1] = 2
[2] = 3
[3] = 4
[4] = 5
[5] = 6
[6] = 7
[7] = 8
[8] = 542979931
[9] = 875896893
```

Each time, `>=8` values are random. I have just no idea why it happens so what's wrong?

Comment: What happens when you step through your code line-by-line using a debugger?

Comment: You should learn how `sizeof()` works first.

Comment: Hint: what's the datatype of `*array`? `array` is a pointer to int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *undefined behavior* in your code. I suppose, doing this:

```
array=(int*)realloc(array,sizeof(int)+sizeof(*array));
```

you expect, that `sizeof(*array)` will return you the size of the whole array, right? But that's not true. `sizeof` is computed at compile time and doing `sizeof(*array)` is actually the same as `sizeof(int)`.

So, to make this array extensible, you need to have additional variable, holding the current number of elements and do something like:

```
array=(int*)realloc(array, sizeof(int) + current_size_of_array * sizeof( int ) );
```

where `current_size_of_array` will be incremented on each loop of the `for`, when you actually add one more element.

Comment: yeah, you are totally right. but ive just cheked my code with another compiler and it works! it's strange...anyway, thaks for explanation!

Comment: @wingsofovnia - it works exactly because it's _undefined behavior_ and this means, that anything can happen.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(*array)` does **not** tell you how large the array is. It tells you how many bytes an int occupies. So each call to realloc is only allocating memory for two int values. Change the `realloc` call to allocate `sizeof(int)` times the number of ints that you want.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(int)+sizeof(*array)`

You think that `sizeof(*array)` is the number of bytes already allocated. You're wrong, `sizeof(*array)` is the size of one `int`. So you're overrunning your buffer, and eventually that causes you a problem.

Before you ask, there is no standard way to get the size already allocated. Normally you need to store it for yourself (or in C++ use something with a more user-friendly interface than `malloc`, such as `vector`). In this case, you don't need the existing size, you can work out the new size required from `i`.

Answer (score 1):

The size of a block of memory allocated by `malloc` is known to the library (`free` only needs the pointer) but there is no portable way to get that number back. You must store in some other variable what is the current size so that you can allocate more space.

In `sizeof(*array)` the `sizeof` operator only considers the **type** of the expression and in your case is `(*(int *))` in other words is the same as `sizeof(int)`.

In C++ this work of remembering the number of elements inside a dynamic array allowing increasing the size is done by the standard class `std::vector`.

As a side note please remember that `x = realloc(x, ...);` is a bad idiom because in case of allocation failure your pointer `x` would be overwritten by `NULL` leaking that memory.